# Embeber Google Maps en iframe

Tags: html, google-maps

Saludos lo que deseo es embeber la página principal de Google maps donde, es decir se vea como una mini ventana en el iframe que me permita buscar direcciones o navegar allí dentro del iframe.

Ahora para esto he probado:

```
  <div class="form-group">
   <iframe class="iframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/" height="100%" frameborder="0" width="100%" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```

el error que muestra por consola:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.com/maps/ does not
>   permit cross-origin framing.

Este iframe esta contenido dentro de una ventana modal de Bootstrap.

Quizá alguna sugerencia sobre cómo puedo agregar esto sin tener que crear una cuenta Google y consumir la API respectiva.

Gracias de antemano..!!!

Answer (score 3):

La página no tiene permitido ese tipo de acceso externo a su servidor. Es por ello que el navegador te arroja ese error:

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate
>   whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a
>   `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>` . Sites can use this to avoid
>   clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded
>   into other sites.

Sin embargo existe una manera de embeber un mapa de Google Maps, pero la **URL** necesita enviar por **GET** el parámetro `output=embed`. Ajunto un ejemplo muy básico (una llamada a la **API** sin credenciales y sin parámetros salvo el mencionado para que funcione):

```html
<div style="width: 100%"><iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://www.google.com/maps?output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div><br />
```

El inconveniente es que no te permite hacer búsquedas, para poder usar esta opción es necesario tener una **API KEY** y programar tú la interfaz y la lógica para las búsquedas.

**Referencias:** [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), [ejemplo de mapa con search-box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)